# Hilbert-Schmidt basis for many qubits - reference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, density-operator

Every density matrix of $n$ qubits can be written in the following way
$$\hat{\rho}=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n=0}^3 t_{i_1i_2\ldots i_n} \hat{\sigma}_{i_1}\otimes\hat{\sigma}_{i_2}\otimes\ldots\otimes\hat{\sigma}_{i_n},$$
where $-1 \leq t_{i_1i_2\ldots i_n} \leq 1$ are real numbers and $\{\hat{\sigma}_0,\hat{\sigma}_1,\hat{\sigma}_2,\hat{\sigma}_3\}$ are the Pauli matrices. In particular for one particle ($n=1$) it is the Bloch representation.

Such representation is used e.g. in a work by Horodecki [arXiv:quant-ph/9607007](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9607007) (they apply $n=2$ to investigate the entanglement of two qubit systems). It is called decomposition in the Hilbert-Schmidt basis.

The question is if there is any good reference for such representation for qubits - either introducing it for quantum applications or a review paper?
I am especially interested in the constrains on $t_{i_1i_2\ldots i_n}$.

Comment: Just having read the question, and possibly not understanding correctly yet, What additional constraints should there be on $t_{i_1i_2\ldots i_n}$ other than leading to a normalised $\hat\rho$?

Comment: @Mark: Normalization is equivalent to $t_{00\ldots0}=1$. All other constrains are related to the nonnegative definiteness (e.g. for $n=1$ there is $t_1+t_2+t_3 \leq 1$).

Comment: With you now. Apparently my brain has already turned in for an early (earlier than me anyway) night.

Comment: It is simply decomposition of  $4^n$ dimensional “vector” with an orthogonal basis. Vector space is space of $2^n \times  2^n$ Hermitian matrices with respect to norm $(A,B) =Tr(AB) = Tr(AB^*)$. But I doubt, it could be called Hilbert-Schmidt decomposition because it is defined for any $n$ and for $n=2$ produces up to 16 terms instead of 4.

Comment: @AlexV I know that it has nothing to do with the Schmidt decomposition.

Comment: So the term due to Hilbert-Schmidt inner product for matrices?

Comment: @AlexV: As well (actually, it is were the name comes from).

Comment: Interestingly, I see many people who have studied extensions of the Bloch vector using the generators of $SU(n)$ as a basis, getting into quite complicated conditions on the Bloch vector (such as http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301152 ). But the way you want, I only know works who did it for $n=2$, such as Fano and the Horodeccy.

Comment: [This](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308019) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I supposed the decomposition itself is rather standard consequence of axioms of quantum mechanics and linear algebra, e.g. section 5.3 in my e-print http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104126v1

Comment: @AlexV: I totally have no problems with the decomposition intself. It is very straightforward (hermitian $2\times2$ matrices $\Rightarrow$ when treated as a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$ then Pauli matrices are an orthonormal basis...).

Comment: I guess, but I never heard about simple expressions for constrains

Comment: @MateusAraújo: Thanks. I found it also as discrete Wigner function http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410117

Comment: @MateusAraújo: Don't forget to post your links as an answer! :)

Comment: Maybe the discrete Wigner function is a bit other story, because they need to use trace on $GF(2^n)$ and exchange components in Hilbert-Schmidt scalar product.

Answer (score 6):

I use this decomposition all the time, but I have never read a paper solely devoted to the topic.  From my experience a complete characterization of the constraints on $t_{i_{1}, t_{2},..t_{n}}$ is tricky, and so if you want to be sure $\rho$ is physical you should calculate the density matrix and its eigenvalues.

However, there are a lot of necessary conditions that have a useful form in this decomposition.  For example, for a positive unit-trace Hermitian operator $\rho$ is follows that

$|t_{i_{1}, i_{2},.. i_{n}}| \leq 1$

$tr ( \rho^{2} ) =\frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{i_{1}, i_{2},.. i_{n}} t_{i_{1}, i_{2},.. i_{n}}^{2} \leq 1 $

The above condition tells us that if we think of $t$ as a vector in a real vector space, then the physical states live within the unit sphere.  This is a bit like the Bloch sphere for 1 qubit but for many qubits we have some other constraints that take the form of hyperplanes.  For every $\vert \psi \rangle$ expressed in the same form
$\vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \vert = \frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{i_{1},i_{2},... i_{n}} Q_{i_{1},i_{2},... i_{n}}\sigma_{i1} \otimes \sigma_{i2}... \sigma_{in}$ we require that

$\langle \psi \vert \rho \vert \psi \rangle \geq 0 $ and so
$\sum Q_{i_{1},i_{2},... i_{n}}t_{i_{1},i_{2},... i_{n}}\geq 0$
which defines a hyperplane.

The problem is you have a hyperplane for every $\psi$ so that requiring $t$ to satisfy every inequality one of the infinite hyperplanes is impossible to check by brute force.  If you want sufficient conditions for positivity of $\rho$ I suspect you have to calculate eigenvalues.

Comment: +1 from me. I use it a lot too, but couldn't think of anything interesting to say!

Answer (score 4):

Claudio Altafini studies precisely this subject, in [Tensor of coherences parameterization of multiqubit density operators for entanglement characterization](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308019) and some follow-ups.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point, I have checked just chapter 4 but there is more, is

R. R. Puri, Mathematical Methods of Quantum Optics, Springer (2001) (see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642087329)).

Comment: Thank you, Jon. In the meantime I found papers about discrete phase space, where $\hat{\sigma}_{\vec{i}}$ is a shift operator (Gibbons, Hoffman, Wootters [quant-ph/0401155](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401155), Paz, Roncaglia, Saraceno [quant-ph/0410117](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410117) and Sec 4.2 of Chris Ferrie's [1010.2701](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2701)).