# Density Matrix for a Pair of Qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

It is known that an arbitrary state (ie. a density matrix) for a qubit can be written as a linear combination of the Pauli matrices

$\rho = \frac{1}{2} (I + r_x \sigma_x + r_y \sigma_y + r_z \sigma_z)$,

where the real numbers $r_x$, $r_y$ and $r_z$ are coordinates of a point in the unit ball.

Can one write a similar decomposition for an arbitrary state in the case of a pair of qubits (ie. a bipartite quantum system), using matrices like $\sigma_x  \otimes  \sigma_x$, and so on?

Comment: Check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629565/positive-matrices-representation/629575#629575) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27719/hilbert-schmidt-basis-for-many-qubits-reference?rq=1). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah yes of course, it's just Hilbert-Schmidt decomposition.  Yes, that's what I meant.